# How can I create a confidence interval in r from a linear model?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

I want to create a linear model of y vs x and use it to find a confidence interval for y given a observed value of x.

So I created some samples:

```
x=rnorm(100,2)
y=rnorm(100,2)
```

and created the linear model:

```
bbbb=lm(y~x)
```

But when I use predict to create the confidence intervals, it gives me a bunch list of confidence intervals rather than a single one?

```
predict(bbbb,x=2,interval="confidence")
```

returns:

```
...
51  2.188294 1.949615 2.426973
52  2.189329 1.932474 2.446183
53  2.176816 1.950111 2.403521
54  2.183961 1.998136 2.369786
...
```

How can I make it return just one confidence interval for y when x=2?

Comment: Questions like this that focus on a specific software implementation are considered Off Topic on [stats.se]. Your question should probably be closed or moved.

Comment: Take out the focus on r, and ask in general how to predict a confidence interval for a given $x$-value.

Comment: @Carl I suspect that's not really the problem here... (suspect this is more about the surprising behaviour of `predict()`...)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yup, it really is off topic. But, you answered it anyway, so +1 for your answer. Now what?

Comment: @Carl Thanks; my answer was too big for a comment so I figured I'd just answer it anyway so at least the OP got help before it was migrated away.

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
predict(bbbb, newdata = data.frame(x = 2), interval  = "confidence")
```

for reasons that are clear when you look at `?predict.lm`.

The `newdata` argument is required to be a data frame. You supplied a length 1 vector. Secondly, because of the way S3 methods work, what you thought you were passing to `newdata` was actually not passed to `newdata` at all. You actually specified a new argument `x` with value `2`, which `predict()` promptly forgot about (it got mopped up by the `...` argument). If `newdata` is not supplied, `predict()` uses the data stored in the fitted model object (`bbbb`) and returns the fitted values plus any requested extras like CI, standard errors etc.